# setOnItemClickListener() not working on custom ListView @ Android

Tags: android, listview

I have Implemented a custom `ListView` by extending `LinearLayout` for every row. Every row has a small thumbnail, a text and a `check box`. The `list view` is deployed properly and I can scroll and fling through it without any problems.

But The `ListView` doesn't seem to respond to the `setOnItemClickListener()` at all, So I had to find a workaround by setting click listener in the `getView()` of the Text inside every row which is obviously creating problem when I am trying to reuse the `adapter`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 48):

Try this
For ListView,

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Also, make sure that for CheckBox inside list item set focusable false

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, the above solution works for detecting clicks on the row but I have 2 buttons in my custom ListView row. How can I tell which button was clicked?

Thanks

Comment: @longhairedsi: please add the following code into getView() method  
button1.setFocusable(false);  
button2.setFocusable(false);  
button1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);  
button2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);  
button1.setOnClickListener(this);  
button2.setOnClickListener(this);  
implement your click listener for button in your adapter(or where you wish....)  
set click listener for list view also.....  
now check your click will work for both.....listview as well as for buttons also

Comment: how do you use above solution for listFragment

Comment: this works, but for that the property `android: clickable` must be false for the "view" in question.

Attention to the parents of the "View" to be not using "android: clickable" on. this will block the pattern selector of your list or derivative.

You can match the pattern selector with a custom selector using the property `android: foreground` like this:

`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <FrameLayout "android: foreground="CUSTOM SELECTOR"">
    <RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout/>
  <.../>
<.../>`

Answer (score 12):

*old answer:* I wrote in [previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512558/304270)

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

will not help when ImageButton is in custom view.. One must use **`button.setFocusable(false);`** during runtime (from java source code)

***Edit:*** There is even more elegant solution. Try to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in root layout of list element. That will make clicks onListItem possible and separately u can handle Button or ImageButton clicks

Answer (score 7):

For a ListView where you set the item views to CheckBox

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414

Answer (score 1):

Set these properties:

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for your all UI elements in your **list_item.xml** file.

if this is not resolved in your adapter set:

```
    v.imageView.setFocusable(false);
    v.imageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you made any ViewHolder in your extended adapter class? If yes, then make an instance of your that placeholder in the setOnItemClickListener() something will may work like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
        View rowView = v;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                // GET INFLATE OF YOUR LAYOUT.
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projectpeopledescrate, null);
             // CUSTOM ViewHolder Class Created in Adapter.
// name,title,comment are my components on the same listview clicked item.
            PPDViewHolder viewHolder = new PPDViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name     = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ppeopledescrvname);
            viewHolder.title    = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ppeopledescrvtime);
            viewHolder.comment  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ppeoplervcomment);
            viewHolder.hiddenLayout = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hiddenCommentPanel); 
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
          // ANOTHER object instance to apply new changes.
        PPDViewHolder holder = (PPDViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
// I've setted up visibility over the components. You can set your onClickListener over your buttons.
        holder.comment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.hiddenLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        holder.hiddenLayout.bringToFront();

    }
```

Hope, you want something same. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have this code

```
this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.v(TAG,"loul");
            }
        });
```

But it didn't work

So i have juste put a onItemSelectedListener under and it work Oo :

```
this.mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Log.v(TAG,"loul");
    }
});
//listener for nothing but it allow OnItemClickListener to work
this.mListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```