# Custom list: EditText consumes list's OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext, custom-lists

I've been implementing a number of custom-lists, all worked fine. Now I'm trying to add an EditText to the list's rows. The rows look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_quest_listrow_categorical_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="blabla"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/tv_quest_listrow_text"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When constructing the list I set an ItemClickListener for the list with `listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);`. This *used to* work fine but fails as soon as there is an EditText in the list rows.

Does anyone have a hint on how to do this?

Regards,
Steff

Comment: Do you mean that items other than the EditText are not calling the listener, or the EditText itself?

Comment: Both, I can click whatever item I want, the list's listener is never called. However, I can set all listeners for the EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414), which has some good information on it. Apparently others have had this issue as well.

Comment: did you see code at the bottom? not sure if that would work in your case.

Comment: another related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518338/setonitemclicklistener-not-working-on-custom-listview-android

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the items of the ListView and set the OnItemClick listner individually for each item

thanks