# ListView with ArrayAdapter: update model when checkbox clicked

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick, android-arrayadapter

I have a List, and ArrayAdapter that could display it (basically as list of CheckBox). MyObejct have few fields, one of them is boolean enabled.

How I could make, that clicking on CheckBox will change corresponding model? Something like:

```
  public class MyObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>{

    private List<MyObject> items;

    public MyObjectAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myobject_checkbox, null);
        }
        MyObject myobject = items.get(position);

        if (myobject!=null){
            //checkbox
            CheckBox cbEnabled = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.enabled);
            if(cbEnabled != null){
                cbEnabled.setChecked(myobject.isEnabled());
                cbEnabled.setText(myobject.getName());
                cbEnabled.setTag(position);
                cbEnabled.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    //how change model. E.g. myobject.setEnabled(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                  }
              });
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post more code here, i.e. your Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would handle this is by making a method that initialises the listview, and once anything is changed, it is re-initialised.

Doing a call like below every time an entry in the listview is changed should make it appear as you want

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.myLayout, myVector));
```

However I understand that this could be computationally expensive compared to other methods the SO community may use

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the Adapter. This will tell the ListView that the underlying data model has changed and it needs to update. There's no need to create a new Adapter, just update the items in it and then call the method I mentioned.

Comment: Also, be careful with checkboxes inside ListViews, do you want to have both the ListItem and Checkbox be clickable? This is generally discouraged (but not impossible to accomplish). The best way to deal with this is to have an ItemOnClickListener and when they click your ListItem you then update your checkbox view to be checked.

Comment: Only Checkbox clickable is enough. But where do i update MyObject (myobject.setEnabled(boolean))?  Could you, please give code example?

Comment: Right, see this (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html), look for Handling User Selections. You can update your object's model in the OnItemClickListener's onClick method. In it, use the adapter variable to retrieve your object (adapter.getItem(position) ) and set the enabled flag there.

Also, if you run into focus probulems, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518338/setonitemclicklistener-not-working-on-custom-listview-android

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example. I have implemented in my one project

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <Button android:id="@+id/checkAll"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Select All"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/uncheckAll"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Unselect All"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkAll"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

checkboxrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private Boolean checkAll=false;
    private MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter;
    private Button buttoncheckAll;
    private Button buttonuncheckAll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] array={"one","two","three","four","five"};


        adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, array);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
          listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        buttoncheckAll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.checkAll);
        buttoncheckAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAll=true;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        buttonuncheckAll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uncheckAll);
        buttonuncheckAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAll=false;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
          private final Context context;
          private final String[] values;

          public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.checkboxrow, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
          }

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkboxrow, parent, false);
            CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            checkbox.setText(values[position]);
            if(checkAll){
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }

            return rowView;
          }
        } 
}
```

Good Luck :)