# How to start Activity with Intent in ListView.setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start a new activity when clicking an item in my `Listview`. But when clicking an item, nothing happens. Nothing is in Logcat message. Both activities are declared in AndroidManifest.

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("test", "hello"); 
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you use a breakpoint or log message to make sure onItemClick is called?

Comment: No. How do I do that?

Comment: `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` should be `listView.setOnItemClickListener`, right? Also, if you are in an Activity, try `MyActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: use  `Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivtiyName.this, SecondActivity.class);`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to set `ItemClick listener` in your listView object.

**<strike>ListView</strike> yourListView.setOnItemClickListener**

Then you need to pass activity's context in `Intent`

Intent myIntent = new Intent **(<strike>view.getContext()</strike>ThisActivityName.this, SecondActivity.class);**

Code snippet :

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisActivityName.this, SecondActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("test", "hello"); 
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your ListView

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Also, make sure that for CheckBox inside list item set focusable false

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Source: [setOnItemClickListener() not working on custom ListView @ Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518338/setonitemclicklistener-not-working-on-custom-listview-android)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code,

```
ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, SecondActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("test", "hello"); 
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
```

Comment: give some description with code to clarify what is the error in current code. *Code-only answer* is not appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple option in ListView You can use follwing code.

```
 lv_1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String s = lv_1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Android.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Iphone.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Window.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;



            }
        }

        ;

    });
```