# setOnItemClickListener() not working on ListView (select always first row)

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom ListView by extending LinearLayout for every row (Contact) and i need to select the item, but the method "setOnItemClickListener()" not working. I have just put a onItemSelectedListener under and now the method "setOnItemClickListener" select always the first item though i select other row

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvPhone = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPhone);

    final List<PhoneBook> listPhoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();
    listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image),"Contact_1","123456789","av1@gmail.com","1"));
    listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image),"Contact_2","123456789","av2@gmail.com","2"));
    listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image),"Contact_3","123456789","av3@gmail.com","3"));

    final PhoneBookAdapter adapter = new PhoneBookAdapter(this, listPhoneBook);
    lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvPhone.setItemsCanFocus(false);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            d.setTitle("Login");
            d.setCancelable(true);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.account);
            d.show();

            Button button_close = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.DCancel);
            button_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button button_login = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.DLogin);
            button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String mName = new String("Ciao");
                    String mPhone;
                    String mEmail;
                    String mID;
                    TextView TextName = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.DName);
                    TextView TextPhone = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.DPhone);
                    TextView TextEmail = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.DEmail);
                    TextView TextID = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.DID);
                    mName=TextName.getText().toString();
                    mPhone=TextPhone.getText().toString();
                    mEmail=TextEmail.getText().toString();
                    mID=TextID.getText().toString();
                    listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image),mName,mPhone,mEmail,mID));
                    lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });


    lvPhone.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView TextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            TextView TextPhone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
            TextView TextEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            TextView TextID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
            String tvName = new String(TextName.getText().toString());
            String tvPhone = new String(TextPhone.getText().toString());
            String tvEmail = new String(TextEmail.getText().toString());
            String tvID = new String(TextID.getText().toString());

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    lvPhone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

PhoneBookAdapter:

```
public class PhoneBookAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private List<PhoneBook> mListPhoneBook;

public PhoneBookAdapter (Context context, List<PhoneBook> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mListPhoneBook = list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListPhoneBook.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListPhoneBook.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PhoneBook entry = mListPhoneBook.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phonebook_row,null);
    }

    ImageView ivAvatar = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(entry.getmAvatar());

    TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvName.setText(entry.getmName());

    TextView tvPhone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    tvPhone.setText(entry.getmPhone());

    TextView tvEmail = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    tvEmail.setText(entry.getmEmail());

    TextView tvID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
    tvID.setText(entry.getmID());

    return convertView;
}

 }
```

`

PhoneBook_row:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvID"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can give a try to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518338/setonitemclicklistener-not-working-on-custom-listview-android?rq=1

Comment: Downvoting as you have changed your question while the solution to your original question was posted below.

Comment: Now the code work. I have changed all your android:clickable="true" to android:clickable="false". Solution suggest by Harsh4789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `PhoneBook_row.xml` with the one I am putting up here, I have tried this and it worked for me. I have changed all your `android:clickable="true"` to `android:clickable="false"`. The reason for doing this is, all of your child views consume click and the result is your parent view i.e `ListView` not getting the click event. Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvID"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please give it a try. It would work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the function "setOnItemClickListener()" working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the override.
Add an **@Override** before the function as shown below.

```
   lvPhone.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }
        });
```

Also adding android:clickable = true in the layout file wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: You have changed your question from the original. However to select the item you have to get the object at that position.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I i have find a solution suggest by Harsh4789

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your question , anyway i believe you can now get the item selected listener working. To get the item which is selected you can use the position as below

```
     lvPhone.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                PhoneBook phoneBook = listPhoneBook.get(position);                 
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phoneBook.getName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
//where getName is a function to get the name in the phonebook class
            }
        });
```